# Merge conflicts between branches when merging to qc and master separately

Tags: git, merge, conflict, rebase

We branch off master (we don't use a dev branch, don't ask why) and then when QA makes a merge request for the branch, we merge it to the qc branch, then when they're done testing, we merge it to the master branch. We never merge qc to master or rebase branches from master to qc, though we may fast-forward the branch to master (through git merge --ff-only master or git rebase -i), though generally just merging across is fine.

However, branches (based on tasks determined by the manager) can be started at different bases, merged into qc in a different order, and merged back into master in a different order than that.

The problem is because we often have to change the same line of code for different features (we're unable to completely avoid this due to the way the code was originally structured and which changes are requested) so we get merge conflicts almost every week, and when things are being merged in different orders to different branches, we can end up having to fix the same conflicts over and over again or merge in different changes to the same line (or have to spread out new lines in different branches to different lines). Whew

To eliminate identical merge conflict fixes, we tried rebasing the branch merged into QC (which may be based on a master commit going way back), but that somehow duplicated the commits on qc and master; we're fine having the commits re-applied to master and losing the ones on qc since we can just merge it back into qc (we merge master into qc whenever it's updated).

How do we avoid these duplicate commits and conflicts, and is there any better way to manage this?

Someone suggested one thing: `git rebase --onto master qc branch` Would this be feasible for branches that would conflict that need to go to master from qc to prevent redundant conflict fix?

Answer (score 0):

Rebasing duplicates commits because that's what rebasing *is*: it is an automated series of `git cherry-pick` operations, and `git cherry-pick` is a commit-copier.

Each object's identity is its hash: `251654c5f6f256fe6e23c2c85f1a70594aae00d4` for instance.  The hash value is a checksum of the contents of the object being hashed.  In the case of a *commit object*, the contents are:

- the name and email for the commit's author;
- the name and email for the committer;
- the identity of the top level source tree for the commit (i.e., a snapshot of every file associated with this commit, represented by the ID of a *tree object*);
- the list of parent commit IDs (more commit-object hashes); and
- the log message for the commit.

Typically, the reason you cherry-pick a commit is to make a slightly altered version—in fact, if you make a bit-for-bit *exactly-the-same* copy you just get the original commit's ID back, since the hash of the same set of input bits is the same value.  With a cherry-picked commit, though, you usually have a slightly different source tree, and pretty much always have a different parent ID.

Consider this (ever so slightly modified, to defeat spam-email scanners) example commit:

```
tree 3b2ac3530e713fc93aa93525bed9623679f99173
parent d2628061aa3b38b9f5dbdcd9136711a5a4ac3a1a
author Chris Torek <chris.torek@somewhere.com> 1459821791 -0700
committer Chris Torek <chris.torek@somewhere.com> 1459821791 -0700

distributed: clarify GUID uniqueness

Add the phrase {Doppelg\"anger commit} in a side-note.
Git and Mercurial allow them as long as they never meet.
```

I can copy this commit by first doing a `git diff` against its parent commit (to show what I changed):

```
diff --git a/distributed.tex b/distributed.tex
index 40fb7fd..6d8854b 100644
--- a/distributed.tex
+++ b/distributed.tex
@@ -41,8 +41,18 @@ to discover and exchange commits
 whenever you direct the system to synchronize your clone
 with a peer.
 In order to make this work correctly,
-these GUIDs really must be globally unique
-(across all repositories).
+these GUIDs really must be globally unique.\sidenote
+{More specifically, they must be unique
+among all clones of a given repository,
+\emph{including forks that may rejoin in the future}.
+This is a somewhat weaker requirement than true global uniqueness.
+For instance, if Alice makes a commit,
+but then destroys it without ever sharing it with anyone else,
+the destroyed commit is allowed to have the same GUID
+as some future commit,
+or a commit in an unrelated repository.
+You can think of this as allowing Doppelg\"anger commits:
+they may share a GUID only as long as they never meet.}
 It would not do
 for Bob to create a \emph{different} commit (in \git)
 or changeset (in \mercurial)
```

Now that I have the diff, I can check out some other commit, apply the diff as a patch, and make a new commit from the result, re-using the log message.  I will get a new commit, with the same log message and the same effect on file `distributed.tex`, but (probably) different `tree` and (definitely) different `parent`, and a new committer time stamp, and therefore a different hash.

That's a single cherry-pick: compare a commit to its parent (to convert it to a changeset), apply that change elsewhere, and make a new commit from the result.  Suppose we *repeat* this operation for a *chain* of commits:

```
... <- B3 <- B4 <- B5   <-- branch-X
  \
   F6 <- F7 <- F8       <-- feature-Y
```

Let's say we copy `F6` through `F8`.  Call the copy of `F6`, `F6'` to distinguish it from the original.  Make the parent of `F6'` be `B5`, and the parent of `F7'` be `F6'`, and the parent of `F8'` be `F7'`, so that we get:

```
                      F6' <- F7' <- F8'
                     /
... <- B3 <- B4 <- B5   <-- branch-X
  \
   F6 <- F7 <- F8       <-- feature-Y
```

Now let's do one last thing.  Let's remove the label `feature-Y`, which is currently stuck on commit `F8`, and paste it on `F8'` instead:

```
                      F6' <- F7' <- F8'   <-- feature-Y
                     /
... <- B3 <- B4 <- B5   <-- branch-X
  \
   F6 <- F7 <- F8       [abandoned]
```

Et voila, we have just rebased—i.e., *copied*—some commits that were on `feature-Y`.  The new copies are now on branch `feature-Y` (during the copying process they were on *no* branch, or rather, on the special anonymous branch you have when you are in "detached HEAD" mode) and the original copies are ... well, still there.

I marked them [abandoned] here, but if there are *other* branch or tag labels that will let you find commit `F8`, you will still be able to see all the original commits.  The `git rebase` command moves the `feature-Y` label, but does not look to see whether some other label keeps the commits visible.

---

**Edit**: the same is true if some of the copied-and-then-abandoned commits are visible via a merge commit, e.g.:

```
                       F6' <- F7' <- F8'   <-- feature-Y
                      /
.... <- B3 <- B4 <- B5   <-- branch-X
\  \
 \  F6 <- F7 <- F8       [abandoned]
  \               \
   C2 <--- C3 <-- C4     <-- branch-C
```

Here `branch-C` makes commits `C2` through `C4` visible, but `C4` is a merge commit which makes `F8` visible.  So now both `F8` (via `C4` from `branch-C`) and `F8'` (via `feature-Y`) will show up when you browse the repository.

This sort of thing controls when and why you should or should not rebase.  Since rebase *copies* commits, you will need to be sure of one of two things: that the originals are really going to be abandoned after all, or that it's OK for the originals to be preserved elsewhere.  [**End edit.**]

---

The other thing that `git rebase` automates for you is choosing *which commits to copy*.  Why did we decide to copy, specifically, `F6` through `F8`?  Why include those three and exclude all others?  This is where the arguments to `git rebase` come in.  Let's return now to this suggestion:

> ```
> git rebase --onto master qc branch
> ```

This is the fully-specified form of `git rebase`.  The very last argument, `branch` in this case, makes `git rebase` start by doing `git checkout branch`.  That is, the extra argument is just passed to `git checkout`.  After that, the extra argument is no more use, so we could do:

```
git checkout branch && git rebase --onto master gc
```

instead.

The `--onto commit` part of the command specifies *where the copies go*.  More specifically, we copied `F6` to `F6'` with its new parent being `B5`.  If you use `--onto` you are specifying this target commit.  (Using a branch name, in this case `master`, just means to use the tip commit on that branch.)

The one remaining argument, `gc` in our case, is what `git rebase` calls `<upstream>`.

If we did *not* specify `--onto`, the `<upstream>` argument would have two roles: it would name the target commit, *and* it would provide `git rebase` the identity of a commit that it should specifically *not* copy (and then *not* copy even more commits, based on that ID).  When we use `--onto`, though, we have already specified the target commit, so the remaining argument has just one remaining role: to specify commits to avoid copying.

The way this "commits to avoid copying" thing works can be a bit tricky to wrap your head around.  We specify one *particular* commit, but rebase uses a trick here that git itself uses all the time.  When we point git to some commit, we can ask it to look at *just* that commit:

```
$ git rev-parse c96a
c96af44caf036cf9f04d77c6146086a4ee422ceb
```

or we can ask it to look at that commit *and all its parent commits* (aka its *ancestry*):

```
$ git rev-list c96a
c96af44caf036cf9f04d77c6146086a4ee422ceb
bca8213e6fda6fdf92b3a5fbc4ee59f755e04a9c
86ac01b3e1d771033e93af93366ace1b586d7c74
bc3fa7a3571231e334f6f06e5610e04227ef1f0b
```

(`rev-parse` does the one-commit thing while `rev-list` does the ancestry variant by default, although `rev-list` is tremendously flexible and is at the heart—or at least the liver or spleen—of many git commands).

Git's `rebase` selects its `<upstream>` argument with ancestry to get commits to *exclude*, while selecting the current branch (after checking it out if you give it that one extra argument) with ancestry to get commits to *include*.  Whatever remains, after excluding the exclusion set, are the commits to copy.

Using the `--onto` form releases `<upstream>` from its double-duty role, so that you can be more selective when you choose which commits to avoid copying.  You will still be copying commits, though, with all that this entails.  In particular, if you use rebase to copy (and then forget about the originals of) commits that *other people* are using, they must also rebase any work they have done that depends on the originals.

Comment: I noticed that the copies only happen if the commits were merged into another branch; unmerged branches would rebase without copying.

Comment: They're still copied.  What happens with the merge case is that *the originals are still reachable*, this time not from a branch name, but instead from the merge commit.  I'll add an example with a merge.